# Criteria for acyclicity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, coherent-cohomology, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. Let $E$ be a line bundle (or, more generally,
a vetor bundle) on $X$.  Are there any nice criteria for acyclicity of $E$ (that is,
for the property $H^i(X,E)=0$ for all $i>0$)? Here $E$ is considered as a coherent sheaf.

In my case the structure sheaf $O_X$ is acyclic and $E$ is ample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for the topic *vanishing theorems*.  There are many such criteria, and perhaps this question should be community wiki?

Anyways, I'll highlight the one of the most common situations, for adjoint line bundles.  Set $\omega_X = \Omega_X^{\dim X}$.  Suppose that:

$E = \omega_X \otimes \text{ample}$

In this case you get the vanishing you want, which is called
the *Kodaira vanishing theorem*.

For example, if $X$ is Calabi-Yau or Fano, then $\omega_X$ is trivial or anti-ample respectively (by definition).  In either case, for any ample $E$, the tensor product $E \otimes \omega_X^{-1}$ is also ample and so $E$ is of the form above, and so the vanishing you want holds.

Of course, many common classes of varieties are these types (there are varieties called log-Calabi-Yau and log-Fano which are also close enough).  For example, toric varieties need not be Fano, but they are always ``close enough'' to give you the vanishing, they are log Fano.

If $X$ is not Calabi-Yau or Fano, then this sort of argument will fail, and you don't always get vanishing for arbitrary ample $E$.  For example, if $X$ is a curve of genus $\geq 2$, then if you set $E = \omega_X$, then $E$ is ample.  However, $H^1(X, E) = H^1(X, \omega_X) = H^0(X, O_X)$ which has dimension 1.

For vector bundles, again there are a lot of options when $E$ is various twists of $\Omega_X^j$.  Look up Kodaira-Nakano-Akizuki vanishing.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful. I'll make it community wiki if there will be more answers.


Comment: The counter example that you gave seems not to satisfy $H^i(X,O_X)=0$ for $i>0$. Do you have an example that satisfy this and with very ample $E$? If yes it will also give a counter example for my question:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90638/can-one-prove-vanishing-of-higher-direct-images-fiber-wise

Thank you again,
Rami